# Combine two images from different cameras using a set of points on Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, transformation

I'm trying to combine two images of the same scene, but taken from two different cameras at a slightly different angle. The images has different resolutions.
I want to select a set of points that represent a map from the first image to the second.
How do I do this process on Android? 
I managed to implement some affine transformations using OpenCV but not sure it could solve my problem here.
One more thing – if I decide later to do this on a live frames instead of two images, will the solution change?

Thanks in advance.